# Postgresql using CASE to return different data depending on existence of other data

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I am trying to create a query that returns different values according to the existence of some data in the DB.
If data exist, I wish to return the data (x columns), if the data does not exists, I return a "count" = 0.

I tried :

```
WITH cart AS (
        SELECT o.id AS order_id, o.ecom_id,COUNT(op.id) as count_product
                    FROM order_products op
                    JOIN orders o ON op.order_id = o.id
                    JOIN order_status os ON os.id = o.status
                    WHERE dealer_id = 19 AND os.level = 0
                    GROUP BY o.id, o.ecom_id limit 1
),
cart_b AS(
    SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM cart) cart_full
)

SELECT CASE
    WHEN cart_full is True THEN(SELECT order_id,ecom_id FROM cart)
    ELSE (SELECT 0 AS count_product)
END
FROM cart_b
```

The problem is :

```
ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
LINE 15:  WHEN cart_full is True THEN(SELECT dropix_order_id,ecom_id ...
```

I understand why, but I do not know how to avoid this and return all data from **cart**.

Is it possible without a plpgsql function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to return:

```
IF cart_full is True THEN
    SELECT order_id, ecom_id FROM cart
ELSE
    SELECT 0 AS count_product
```

Cannot be returned as a single query.  Why?  Because there are different columns.  I would suggest that you return all three columns.  If there are no rows, then the other columns will be `NULL`.

For that, you can use a query like this:

```
WITH cart AS (
        SELECT o.id AS order_id, o.ecom_id, COUNT(op.id) as count_product
        FROM order_products op JOIN
             orders o
             ON op.order_id = o.id JOIN
             rder_status os ON os.id = o.status
        WHERE dealer_id = 19 AND os.level = 0
        GROUP BY o.id, o.ecom_id 
        LIMIT 1
       )
SELECT o.id AS order_id, o.ecom_id, count_product
FROM cart
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, 0
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
with cart as (...)
select order_id, ecom_id, count_product from cart
union all
select x.*
from (values(null, null, 0)) as x(order_id, ecom_id, count_product)
where not exists (select 1 from cart)
```

The query runs in the cte. If it returns something, then we use it as the result; else, we return a record with fixed, `null` values for the first two columns and `0` as count.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your query. I have this error : ERROR:  UNION types integer and text cannot be matched